# Change emoji font to the Windows style

Tags: emoji

Is it possible to change the way Mac OS Mojave renders emoji from the Mac versions to the Windows versions? I prefer the darker, more vibrant Windows emoji.

Answer (score 1):

I think not, because Apple, MS, and Google all use different incompatible formats for color emoji fonts.